# MySQL CodeIgniter Select or not from second table based on column of first Select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables the students which has students.id, students.name

A table called students_classes which has students_classes.students_id and students_classes.classes_id and is for linking the students with their classes.

And a table named class, which has class.id, class.title, class.begin , class.end and class.type. class.type can be A or B.

A is nothing special, but B means that the class has divisions, and that the time in the table actually shows when the first division starts and when the last ends.

That is wrong though because the students are split into divisions for each class and I need the time from a single division and not all divisions.

I thought about creating another table named divisions with divison.id, division.begin, division.end and division.class_id as foreign of class.id.

Now my problem is, how do I create a select or a condition that checks the class and IF class.type is B, goes to divisions and takes the time from there instead of from class.begin and class.end?

My select function before the implementation of the "divisions" part:

```
function select_classes($student_id)
{
    $this->db->select('class.title as t, class.type as tp,
    class.begin as b, class.end as e');
    $this->db->from('class');
    $this->db->join('students_classes', 'class.id = students_classes.class_id');
    $this->db->join('students', 'students.id = students_classes.students_id');
    $this->db->where('students.id', $student_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

What this does is take a student's id and returns what classes he has and at what time. I now want it to also take into account if the class.type is B and if it is, it should join the divisions table and take times from it instead of the class table.

Also is it possible to make it return the changed begin/end times (if it uses the division table) as b and e like the starting statment? (because I call them as class->b, class->e in the view)

PS: Im also assuming that there will be a new students_classes.division_id column in the students_classes in order to link the students with their respective divisions as the students_classes is used for linking the stuends with their classes...

Comment: I think, you should create second query.

Comment: Please update your question with table schema and expected output

Comment: @Sifd: what will be the value of the `students_classes.division_id` for the students of `type A` ??

Comment: most likely NULL or 0 because he is nost supposed to care for divisions as type A means that there are no divisions, I will update with table schema

Comment: Reframed your schema a bit. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Keeping `times` in 2 different tables will **not** be a good option.
2) Assuming the type A's to be in some particular division (same for all A's).
3) Now collect all the classes and their divisions and all of their timings (basically **all possible combination**) in **one table** and link your `students_classes` table to it.

Reframed your schema as **[(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4db6/6)**,

**1)** *students*

```
| id |      name |
|----|-----------|
|  1 |  Student1 |
|  2 |  Student2 |
|  3 |  Student3 |
|  4 |  Student4 |
|  5 |  Student5 |
|  6 |  Student6 |
|  7 |  Student7 |
|  8 |  Student8 |
|  9 |  Student9 |
| 10 | Student10 |
```

**2)** *classes*

```
| id |  title | type |
|----|--------|------|
|  1 | class1 |    A |
|  2 | class2 |    B |
|  3 | class3 |    B |
|  4 | class4 |    A |
|  5 | class5 |    A |
|  6 | class6 |    A |
|  7 | class7 |    B |
```

**3)** *divisions*

```
| id | title |
|----|-------|
|  1 |  div1 |
|  2 |  div2 |
|  3 |  div3 |
```

**4)** *classes_divisions*

```
| id | class_id | division_id | begin |   end |
|----|----------|-------------|-------|-------|
|  1 |        1 |           1 | 07:30 | 13:30 |
|  2 |        2 |           1 | 08:30 | 14:30 |
|  3 |        2 |           2 | 08:00 | 14:00 |
|  4 |        3 |           2 | 07:00 | 12:00 |
|  5 |        3 |           3 | 06:30 | 11:30 |
|  6 |        4 |           1 | 07:15 | 12:15 |
|  7 |        5 |           1 | 06:20 | 12:20 |
|  8 |        6 |           1 | 06:50 | 12:50 |
|  9 |        6 |           1 | 07:50 | 13:50 |
| 10 |        6 |           2 | 08:50 | 14:50 |
| 11 |        6 |           3 | 09:50 | 15:50 |
```

**5)** *students_classes*

```
| id | student_id | class_division_id |
|----|------------|-------------------|
|  1 |          1 |                 1 |
|  2 |          2 |                 2 |
|  3 |          3 |                 2 |
|  4 |          4 |                 3 |
|  5 |          5 |                 4 |
|  6 |          6 |                 5 |
|  7 |          7 |                 6 |
|  8 |          8 |                 6 |
|  9 |          9 |                 6 |
| 10 |         10 |                 7 |
```

Now a simple `JOIN` with knowing only the `student_id`,

```
SELECT classes.title           AS t, 
       classes.type            AS tp, 
       classes_divisions.begin AS b, 
       classes_divisions.end   AS e 
FROM   students_classes 
       JOIN classes_divisions 
         ON students_classes.class_division_id = classes_divisions.id 
       JOIN classes 
         ON classes_divisions.class_id = classes.id 
WHERE  students_classes.student_id = 2;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
| t      | tp   | b     | e     |
|--------|------|-------|-------|
| class2 |    B | 08:30 | 14:30 |
```

Comment: This is almost what I am searching for, the schema is exactly as mine (I havent uploaded it because I cant find how to :( ) 

But my problem (and why im trying to go around this method) is that when a class is of type A, then it does not have divisions, only class.type B has divisions.

Comment: 2) Assuming the type A's to be in some particular division (same for all A's).

Comment: Nope yours is not exactly the same. You are maintaining times in 2 different tables and I've merged it in one table. Please check again.

Comment: Well, saw the code thoroughly this time and its almost what im searching for, but, the thing is, that a student is supposed to get linked always to a class and a division and not the combination of those two (not the class_division_id) because (as in ur example) there may be a class that is run in 2 different times, and if that happens I want all the students registered on those classes and/or divisions of classes to get automaticaly updated.... 

Or at least thats how I thought about it, if its wrong (as my time thing is now that I realized it, thnx :) ) then plz tell me...

Comment: In the case I was not understood because I dont speak engish that well: the `classes` of `type B` are split in `divisions`, the `classes` of `type A` are not, BUT we will assume they are all in `division 1` the `students` are in `classes` and IF some of their classes is of `type B` then they need to be in a division of that class too (`type B` without division does not make sense and should error out), `classes` of `type A` dont have divisions so a student choses only the class and it should be default that they are in division 1 of a `type A` class.

Comment: I don't think it is... because in your example, If a student is in class6 (which is a class of `type A` ) he shouldnt have to get linked to class6 4 times in the `students_classes` table ( because if you see in `classes_divisions`, `classes.id == 6` happens 4 times )

Comment: OK. Not clear with the requirements. Let me know if I can help further in anyway.

Comment: Let me ask you something that might help me: If you want in the same querry but with `WHERE  students_classes.student_id = 5;` to have as output every class6 begin and end times, how do you achieve that? That is my problem, I want it to be able to show every `begin` and `end` when its `type A` (because there are no `divisions` in `type A` classes) but only specific `begin` and `end` times when its of `type B` (based on what `division` of the said class the student is enroled in)

Comment: Then the `students_classes.class_division_id` should be `2` then. The `students_classes` table should be prefilled by the admin (i.e. you).

Comment: Sorry I missclicked my last comment and didnt edit it in time before ur awnser...

Comment: Seems like im gona rewrite the db around this and change some things if needed... thnx for everything :)

Comment: Yes I guess that would be nice option. Happy to help (if any) :-)